# Image Zoom and crop using jquery

Tags: zooming, crop

Want a live code which is used to crop and zoom image and save it. Have looked lot of sites. It works on demo but after downloading it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jquery plugin](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit). You can find a demo [here](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/). 
You will be getting a base64 imagedata. You can convert that to image using 
`<img src="<< base-64 encoded data string>>" />` where you will get a link to the image. 
Else create an object of type image and store the data to the src tag.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = << base-64 encoded data string>>
```

Comment: someother please @Rakesh Nair

Comment: the image cannot be stored. it returns as a base64

Comment: @ParthibanMK Try this.